# Calculating previous chance figure for use in chi square test

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, chi-squared

SO, I am using a script to calculate the number of occurrences of times a person appears in the list on dates prior to the date specified in the row and a 1 occurs in column 6, and also calculates The number of times a person (column 7) appears in the list on dates prior to the date specified in the row (note they are sorted chronologically.) (Using zero based column referencing)

#### Example Data set

```
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,1,George Smith
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,2,Ted James
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,3,Emma Lilly
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,5,George Smith
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,6,4,Tom Phillips
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,2,Tom Phillips
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,5,George Smith
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,1,Emma Lilly
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,6,George Smith
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,6,Ted James
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,2,George Smith
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,4,George Smith
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,1,George Smith
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,5,Tom Phillips
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,3,Emma Lilly
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,1,Ted James
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,2,George Smith
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,4,Emma Lilly
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,5,Tom Phillips
```

#### The code I am using

```
import csv
import datetime
import copy
from collections import defaultdict

with open(r"C:\Temp\test.csv") as i, open(r"C:\Temp\resuls.csv", "wb") as o:
    rdr = csv.reader(i)
    wrt = csv.writer(o)

    data, currdate = defaultdict(lambda:[0, 0, 0, 0]), None
    for line in rdr:
        date, name = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[0], '%d/%m/%Y'), line[7]

        if date != currdate or not currdate:
            for v in data.itervalues(): v[:2] = v[2:]
            currdate = date

        wrt.writerow(line + data[name][:2])

        data[name][3] += 1
        if line[6] == "1": data[name][2] += 1
```

#### This returns:

```
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,1,George Smith,0,0
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,2,Ted James,0,0
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,3,Emma Lilly,0,0
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,5,George Smith,0,0
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,6,4,Tom Phillips,0,0
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,2,Tom Phillips,0,1
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,5,George Smith,1,2
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips,0,1
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,1,Emma Lilly,0,1
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,6,George Smith,1,2
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,6,Ted James,0,1
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips,0,3
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,2,George Smith,1,4
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,4,George Smith,1,4
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,1,George Smith,1,4
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,5,Tom Phillips,0,3
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,3,Emma Lilly,1,2
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,1,Ted James,0,2
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,2,George Smith,2,7
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,4,Emma Lilly,1,2
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,5,Tom Phillips,0,5
```

Ultimately I will be wanting to perform a chi squared on the percentage data I am generating. However for now all I want to be able to achieve is to be able to calculate and sum the fractional chance of any one person within a unique data class (column 2) and append it to the csv as a new column. I am not sure If the code I have been used can be edited to achieve this as an all in one piece of code. Any constructive suggestions or comments on how this can best be done would be appreciated.

#### My desired output would be the following:

```
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,5,1,George Smith,0,0,0
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,5,2,Ted James,0,0,0
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,5,3,Emma Lilly,0,0,0
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,5,5,George Smith,0,0,0
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,5,4,Tom Phillips,0,0,0
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,5,2,Tom Phillips,0,1,0.2, He gets 0.2 because there was a 1 in 5 chance for previous occurrences on dates prior to today. 1/5
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,5,5,George Smith,1,2,0.4, He gets 0.4 because there was a 2 in 5 chance for previous occurrences on dates prior to today. 2/5
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,5,3,Tom Phillips,0,1,0.2
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,5,1,Emma Lilly,0,1,0.2
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,5,6,George Smith,1,2,0.4
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,6,Ted James,0,1,0.2
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips,0,3,0.6
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,2,George Smith,1,4,0.8
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,4,George Smith,1,4,0.8
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,1,George Smith,1,4,0.8
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,5,Tom Phillips,0,3,0.4
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,3,Emma Lilly,1,2,0.4
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,1,Ted James,0,2,0.366666667
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,2,George Smith,2,7,1.3
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,4,Emma Lilly,1,2,0.4
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,5,Tom Phillips,0,5,0.733333333
```

Comment: do you get the results you are expecting with your code?

Comment: The code I have provided, calculates the following (and yeh :) it works correctly) : Calculates the number of times a person appears in the list on dates prior to the date specified in the row and a 1 occurs in column 6. Calculates the number of times a person (column 7) appears in the list on dates prior to the date specified in the row (note they are sorted chronologically.)

Comment: Can you take a look at this http://pastebin.com/4KtATqPB?

Comment: @elyase Yeh it is for dates prior to the date of that row. I.e only count occurrences from previous data.

Comment: ah ok, so the next occurrence `03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,5,George Smith,1,2` means found once with a "1" and twice in total before the current date?

Comment: Exactly :) Now I need to work out how to get the expected value for each of these occurrences. For instance by the time of the row `03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,5,George Smith,1,2` George would have have an expected of 0.5 (4/1 is 0.25 and he has two chances in first class, so 0.25 * 2) and an observed of 1. Which can obviously be used to calculate the chi squared value.

Comment: @elyase Started a 100 point bounty on this question now.

Comment: Can you tidy up the question a bit. The first paragraph duplicates itself; at least I find it imprecise. And the second paragraph containing the question is not straightforward.  You'll get a better response if we don't have to think hard to see what you want to achieve.

Comment: @AEA, weird that the question has not yet been answered. I think you should try to improve the description of the problem. I understand now what your code does, but it is still not clear what you want to achieve. For example "When each unique class there is an associated …" seems grammatically incorrect.

Comment: Yeh just re writing some parts of it now. To hopefully clarify it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say `For instance by the time of the row 03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,5,George Smith,1,2 George would have have an expected of 0.5 (4/1 is 0.25 and he has two chances in first class, so 0.25 * 2) and an observed of 1.`. Can you try to clarify what you mean here?

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify what is it that you want? Perhaps with simpler data? I'm not clear if you mean "chi square test" (i.e. statistical significance) or "statistical relationship", and if the latter then relationship between which (random) variables?

Comment: @qarma I am looking at the statistical significance of each percentage data generated for instance chi square = (Observed-Expected)^2/Expected

Comment: Please define "observed" and "expected". I can guess the earlier but not the latter. Also please clarify your definition of "chance" in edit1. Is it per class or per class-person? Is person's presence a binary flag or a counter?

Comment: Hello Quarma, I am getting concerned about the amount of time this bounty has left. The observed is column 8 in the returned csv (this is the number of times a person appears in the list on dates prior to the date specified in the row and where a 1 occurs in column 6) and the expected is the sum of the fractional chances assigned calculated by summing the chances of each name on dates prior to the date specified in the row. I will provide an example in next comment.

Comment: In order to do this the code needs to remember the fractional chances from each Class for those same numbers counted. For instance for the both the Emma Lilly's on the 05/01/2005 they occurred twice previously (previous date) the first time they had a 1/4 chance the second time they had a 1/6 chance (dependant on the class size, i.e. 1 divided by the length of the class in column 2 for each time previous occurrence)

Comment: All what was just described defines the expexcted. Sum the previous chances in this case 1/6 (0.166) + 1/4 (0.25) and we get an expected value of 0.416 . The observed is the sum of column 8 in the returned csv (this is the number of times a person appears in the list on dates prior to the date specified in the row and where a 1 occurs in column 6.) So in this case it is 1. So here our chi squared = (1-0.416)^2/0.416

Comment: @AEA, *"For instance for the both the Emma Lilly's … second time they had a 1/6 chance"*, where is the 6 coming from? *"When each unique class there is"*, I am not a native english speaker but this sentence really confuses me. My advice why don't you rewrite the post from scratch explaining the algorithm you follow to get to each of the whished columns. At the end give an example of the expected values for all (also intermediate like class count) expected columns. This way we know what we have to reproduce and once we get it done we know is the same thing you want.

Comment: @AEA, this is a problem that normally takes minutes, not days to get solved, so I am pretty sure that if you take your time to explain it correctly you will have it solved in no time.

Comment: I have completely restructured the question with a desired output no reference to chi squared as I can perform this in a subsequent edit.

Comment: @AEA, Ok, now how about adding how you get to the last column's values. All I see is *"… calculate and sum the fractional chance of any one person within a unique data class (column 2)"*. For example George appears 2 times in the class `xpv`. Then why is his fractional chance 0 instead of 2/4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is not supposed to be a complete answer to your question ( because it is kind of ambiguous what you are trying to do ) but just to show you how [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) fit naturally in this sort of calculations; you will also have the luxury of calling columns by name rather than by index.

Let's say you have a `test.csv` file like this:

```
date,x0,cls,x1,x2,x3,tag,name
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,1,George Smith
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,2,Ted James
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,3,Emma Lilly
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,5,George Smith
...
```

where i have assigned names to each column. You may read this file into a pandas dataframe by

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv( 'test.csv', index_col=None )
```

`df` will look like this:

```
          date    x0         cls  x1     x2  x3  tag          name
0   02/01/2005  Data   Class xpv   4  11yo+   4    1  George Smith
1   02/01/2005  Data   Class xpv   4  11yo+   4    2     Ted James
2   02/01/2005  Data   Class xpv   4  11yo+   4    3    Emma Lilly
3   02/01/2005  Data   Class xpv   4  11yo+   4    5  George Smith
...
```

I drop the columns which you are not using ( this is just for the purposes of demonstration, you do not have to drop these columns )

```
df.drop( labels=['x0', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3'], axis=1, inplace=True )
```

now `df` looks like below:

```
          date         cls  tag          name
0   02/01/2005   Class xpv    1  George Smith
1   02/01/2005   Class xpv    2     Ted James
2   02/01/2005   Class xpv    3    Emma Lilly
3   02/01/2005   Class xpv    5  George Smith
...
```

Suppose you want to find the cumulative number of times each person will appear in the dates *before* each day:

```
pv = df.pivot_table( cols='name',
                     rows='date',
                     values='tag',
                     aggfunc=len ).shift( 1 ).fillna( 0 ).cumsum( )
```

The api documentation ( see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html) ) includes a detailed description of what each method is doing. Now you have the pivot table `pv` which looks like this

```
date        Emma Lilly  George Smith  Ted James  Tom Phillips
02/01/2005           0             0          0             0
03/01/2005           1             2          1             1
04/01/2005           2             4          1             3
05/01/2005           2             7          2             5
```

alternatively one could use `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['date', 'name'])['name'].aggregate(len).unstack( ).shift( 1 ).fillna( 0 ).cumsum( )
```

To do the same calculations but only for `tag == 1`, you may do

```
idx = df.tag == 1
pv1 = df[ idx ].pivot_table( cols='name',
                             rows='date',
                             values='tag',
                             aggfunc=len ).shift( 1 ).fillna( 0 ).cumsum( )
```

or using `groupby` syntax:

```
df[ df.tag == 1 ].groupby(['date', 'name'])['name'].aggregate(len).unstack( ).shift( 1 ).fillna( 0 ).cumsum( )
```

which will be:

```
date        Emma Lilly  George Smith  Ted James
02/01/2005           0             0          0
03/01/2005           0             1          0
04/01/2005           1             1          0
05/01/2005           1             2          0
```

To fill out the two new columns, we write a helper function to fall back to 0, if a value is missing:

```
def lookup( pivot_table, col, idx, fall_back=0 ):
    try:
        return pivot_table[ col ][ idx ]
    except KeyError:
        return fall_back

df[ 'cnt1' ] = [ lookup( pv1, row[ 'name' ], row[ 'date' ] ) for idx, row in df.iterrows( ) ]
df[ 'cnt' ] = [ lookup( pv, row[ 'name' ], row[ 'date' ] ) for idx, row in df.iterrows( ) ]
```

and we get:

```
          date         cls  tag          name  cnt1  cnt
0   02/01/2005   Class xpv    1  George Smith     0    0
1   02/01/2005   Class xpv    2     Ted James     0    0
2   02/01/2005   Class xpv    3    Emma Lilly     0    0
3   02/01/2005   Class xpv    5  George Smith     0    0
4   02/01/2005   Class tn2    4  Tom Phillips     0    0
5   03/01/2005   Class tn2    2  Tom Phillips     0    1
6   03/01/2005   Class tn2    5  George Smith     1    2
7   03/01/2005   Class tn2    3  Tom Phillips     0    1
8   03/01/2005   Class tn2    1    Emma Lilly     0    1
9   03/01/2005   Class tn2    6  George Smith     1    2
10  04/01/2005   Class tn2    6     Ted James     0    1
11  04/01/2005   Class tn2    3  Tom Phillips     0    3
12  04/01/2005   Class tn2    2  George Smith     1    4
13  04/01/2005   Class tn2    4  George Smith     1    4
14  04/01/2005   Class tn2    1  George Smith     1    4
15  04/01/2005   Class tn2    5  Tom Phillips     0    3
16  05/01/2005  Class 22zn    3    Emma Lilly     1    2
17  05/01/2005  Class 22zn    1     Ted James     0    2
18  05/01/2005  Class 22zn    2  George Smith     2    7
19  05/01/2005  Class 22zn    4    Emma Lilly     1    2
20  05/01/2005  Class 22zn    5  Tom Phillips     0    5
```

I could keep going if I had any idea how you are calculating that last column. for example why "Tom Phillips" gets 0.2 in the 6th row?!

**edit**: ok, let's keep going. we need to find out how many times each person appears on each date; that is another pivot table:

```
appr = df.pivot_table( cols='name',
                       rows='date',
                       values='tag',
                       aggfunc=len ).fillna( 0 )
```

or

```
df.groupby( ['date', 'name'] )['name'].aggregate(len).unstack( ).fillna( 0 )
```

output:

```
date        Emma Lilly  George Smith  Ted James  Tom Phillips
02/01/2005           1             2          1             1
03/01/2005           1             2          0             2
04/01/2005           0             3          1             2
05/01/2005           2             1          1             1
```

and how many people appear on each date:

```
total_appr = appr.sum( axis=1 )
```

output:

```
date
02/01/2005    5
03/01/2005    5
04/01/2005    6
05/01/2005    5
```

to compute cumulative fractions you can simply divide each row by the total, shift by one ( because we lookup the previous dates ) and calculate cumulative sum:

```
frac = appr.apply( lambda x: x / total_appr ).shift( 1 ).fillna( 0 ).cumsum( )
df[ 'frac' ] = [ frac[ row[ 'name' ] ][ row[ 'date' ] ] for idx, row in df.iterrows( ) ]
```

now `df` looks like below:

```
          date         cls  tag          name  cnt1  cnt      frac
0   02/01/2005   Class xpv    1  George Smith     0    0  0.000000
1   02/01/2005   Class xpv    2     Ted James     0    0  0.000000
2   02/01/2005   Class xpv    3    Emma Lilly     0    0  0.000000
3   02/01/2005   Class xpv    5  George Smith     0    0  0.000000
4   02/01/2005   Class tn2    4  Tom Phillips     0    0  0.000000
5   03/01/2005   Class tn2    2  Tom Phillips     0    1  0.200000
6   03/01/2005   Class tn2    5  George Smith     1    2  0.400000
7   03/01/2005   Class tn2    3  Tom Phillips     0    1  0.200000
8   03/01/2005   Class tn2    1    Emma Lilly     0    1  0.200000
9   03/01/2005   Class tn2    6  George Smith     1    2  0.400000
10  04/01/2005   Class tn2    6     Ted James     0    1  0.200000
11  04/01/2005   Class tn2    3  Tom Phillips     0    3  0.600000
12  04/01/2005   Class tn2    2  George Smith     1    4  0.800000
13  04/01/2005   Class tn2    4  George Smith     1    4  0.800000
14  04/01/2005   Class tn2    1  George Smith     1    4  0.800000
15  04/01/2005   Class tn2    5  Tom Phillips     0    3  0.600000
16  05/01/2005  Class 22zn    3    Emma Lilly     1    2  0.400000
17  05/01/2005  Class 22zn    1     Ted James     0    2  0.366667
18  05/01/2005  Class 22zn    2  George Smith     2    7  1.300000
19  05/01/2005  Class 22zn    4    Emma Lilly     1    2  0.400000
20  05/01/2005  Class 22zn    5  Tom Phillips     0    5  0.933333
```

my numbers are different from yours on two rows in the last column. so either I got your calculations wrong or you miscalculated those two numbers.

Comment: I hope my edits help explain how the last column is calculated in my desired output?

Comment: Its going to take me a while to digest it all, but I want this pandas knowledge it looks like it makes table based data manipulation much easier.

Comment: I haven't even tested all the code, but I love this answer, I really appreciate you breaking it down in the way that you have. So I am giving you the bounty. Possibly one of the best answers I have recieved to any of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straightforward, except that it's not clear what calculation you mean by "the fractional chance of any one person within a unique data class". For example, your data begins with 5 rows for data class `xpv`, in which `George Smith` appears twice. What "fractional chance" do you want to see for George Smith? What do you want to see for the others (who appear once)? Why does your sample output show only zeroes next to the `xpv` rows?

The answer may depend on whether the date classes recur on later dates, and on whether this matters to your calculation; but if you can explain how you calculate the values for the first 5, perhaps the rest will become clear. (If not, please explain the second set, where the values do become non-zero.)

PS. Maybe this is somehow addressed in the discussion in the comments, but TL;DNR. If you can improve the question, it will be easy to give a correct answer.

Comment: Yeh this seems to be the reply from both yourself and runnerup, I will try and clarify this further in my question. But for now I will try and answer it here with regards to the named example.